# List all the members of the set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to list out the members of the following set:

$\mathbb Z\cap(\mathbb Z^+\cup\mathbb Z^-)'$

Meaning the set of integers intersects the complement of the union of the sets of positive and negative integers.

Comment: You know what the sets mean, so why don't you evaluate yourself? Where are you stuck.

Comment: I tried solving this using Venn diagrams but I got stuck when I drew the complement of the union of the positive and negative sets which was everything outside of where they intersect. So in one venn diagram I had two circles representing the complement of the union of both the positive and negative integers and another venn diagram with one circle representing the set of integers and visually I couldn't figure out where the set of integers intersected the venn diagram which showed everything but the intersection of the union of the positive and negative integer sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the above answer is correct. For a longer explanation, the approach is basically as follows:

$(\mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \mathbb{Z}^-)$ would be the set of all positive and negative integers. The complement of this set would be the set that has neither positive nor negative integers. The only integer that fits this description is $0$.

So then you're basically looking at the intersection of the set of all integers, $\mathbb{Z}$ $\cap$ {$0$} and the set consisting of one element, $0$. The intersection is clearly $0$. 
$\fbox{}$

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the following might solve it, if I understand your problem correctly:

$\left( Z^{+} \cup Z^{-}\right)'= \{0\}$ then

$Z \cap \{0\} = \{0\}$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This makes sense to me. When I was trying to figure it out I used venn diagrams and the image just confused me since the venn diagram for the complement of the positive and negative sets was essentially the universal set. So does it mean that any set that intersects the universal set just the universal set?